# How do I get spotlight/shadow position to remain exactly same relative horizontal center position regardless of zoom?

Tags: html, css

In the following fiddle I successfully have made the spotlight stay in the same place (horizontally centered) except for when my zoom factor is too large.  In other words, when I zoom in my spot light does not stay in the center of the horizontal view port.

Please note the use of **`.spotlight-2:before`** to fill the left portion of the shadow on the viewport.  This is what I needed to prevent non shaded region from appearing.

How do I make the spotlight stay in center horizontally and not shift to the right when zooming in closely in the browser?

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/u0onf23y/

**Resulting Output**

https://jsfiddle.net/u0onf23y/embedded/result/

**CSS**

```
td .div{
  height: 400px;
}

.extend-full {
  padding-left: 3000px;
  margin-left: -3000px;
  padding-right: 3000px;
  margin-right: -3000px; }

    .spotlight-2{
        top: 0px;
        margin-left:-80px;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        background: radial-gradient(10px 10px at 560px 400px, transparent 0, transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 160px);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(10px 10px at 560px 400px, transparent 0, transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 160px);
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(10px 10px at 560px 400px, transparent 0, transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 160px);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(10px 10px at 560px 400px, transparent 0, transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 160px);
        margin-left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
        z-index: 10;
      };
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10; }

    .account-settings-confirm-container-overlay {
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: white !important;
      height: 99px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 12px;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
    .spotlight-2:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;   
      left: -100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to use all % based CSS, no?

Comment: `z-index: 10;
      };
      position: absolute;` -- is that intentional??

Comment: @Scott, I believe in my local design my css has other elements with a larger z-index, so I use 10 as a value to ensure that this is above the below elements like the table and to prevent clicking on the elements behind the shadow.

Comment: uhm... there's a `};` in the *middle of that CSS property list* -- that's what I meant.

Comment: @RonRoyston, is there an issue using pixel values because my local design uses a bootstrap container that zooms in center and does not pull apart like container-fluid behaves?

Comment: The thing about absolute positioned elements is they do not render well across devices.  For example, on a mobile device, if you focus on an input element, the virtual keyboard will display over the input.  Use margin instead.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for the catch, let me try this change now.

Comment: The proposed fix did not have an effect either negatively or positively.  It did not affect the behavior.  @RonRoyston, are you suggesting usage of margin-left to keep the position of the spotlight fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flexbox.  See example fullpage http://codepen.io/rhroyston/full/qadGgd/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#viewport{
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  
} 

.a{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey inset;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very for this example.  I will need to modify to make the vertical position responsive the area that zooms out. Since my example zooms out to the top then I will make modifications to adjust this effect.   But, I will definitely use this approach to keep the flexbox centered.

Comment: just remove `align-items: center;` and it will display at the top.

Comment: I did try this, the caveat is the spotlight keeps veering to the right on closer zoom in levels.  It is that I am trying to suppress or control to stay exactly in the horizontal (not necessarily vertical) center.

Comment: Adding   text-align: center;   left: 50%;   margin-left: -25px; under #viewport element has completely controlled the item to stay centered.  I will now have to do more tweaking.  But it is close.